# How to translate ∃x ∀y ∀z ( ( F(x,y) ∧ F(x,z) ∧ F(y≠z) ) → ¬F(y,z) )?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

> Translate the following expression to English
>
> $$∃x∀y∀z ( ( F(x,y) ∧ F(x,z) ∧ F(y≠z) ) → ¬F(y,z) )$$

So, I have two answers:

1. There is a person who does not have two friends that are friends of one another.
2. There is person who has two friends that are not friends each other.

Are they both right?

Comment: Only first is corect

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that $F(x \neq y)$ is actually meant to be $x \neq y$.

Talking about 'friends' implies the symmetric property; if $x$ is a friend of $y$ then $y$ is a friend of $x$ too, that is: $\forall x \forall y F(x,y) \leftrightarrow F(y,x)$, which you don't know if it holds. Try instead to interpret $F(x,y)$ using the loving relation: '$x$ loves $y$' (but sadly $y$ may not love $x$...).

Under the later interpretation, the proposition can be paraphrased as 'there is a person $x$ who either loves only him/her-self, or all the people that he/she loves (if there exist at least two of them) do not love each other'.

Tip: In order to avoid assuming extra properties, you should always interpret predicates like $P(x,y)$ as a basic subject-verb-object English sentence (somebody does something to someone), that's what predicates are meant for, after all!

Comment: "[...] do not love each other" is not written in the original statement, symmetry is deduced by switching $y$ and $z$

Comment: That's right, this symmetry needs not to be explicitly stated in the original sentence. Also, to criticize my own answer, I should write 'there is a person $x$ who all the **other** people that etc...', otherwise I imply that $x$ cannot love themselves. I'll correct it!

Comment: Well, it is true that $x$ cannot love themselves if there is any $y\neq x$ that $x$ loves.

Comment: I just noticed... Logic is too tricky! Please make sure there isn't anything else I didn't see.

Comment: I would suggest (funny?) alternative "There is a person $x$ such that there is no love between any two people loved by $x$", but it has the same symmetry issue. Literal translation would be this "There is a person $x$ such that for any two people $y$ and $z$ loved by $x$, $y$ doesn't love $z$", but any such construct will sound awkward because the symmetry is natural here. I'm not really sure whether purposely avoiding symmetric translation is good or not, even though it is not explicitly written in the original statement. I just wanted to make sure that OP doesn't miss on the subtlety.

Comment: Nevertheless, +1 for the last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! It's good you pointed out that symmetry issue. In my opinion when we paraphrase a logic sentence we are free to use some natural language conventions to help us grasp its meaning better. If we stick to structure though, rewriting the sentence as $\exists x \forall y \forall z (x loves y) \land (x loves z) \land (y \neq z) \implies \lnot (y loves z)$.